# Support gems for auto-defense skills

Tags: path-of-exile

As a melee shield user on hardcore I like to play with the auto-defend skills. Reckoning, Riposte and Vengeance. However when it comes to support gems it seems some of them don't work. I've tried Life on Hit, since the point of these skills is to act defensively.

Is there an overview of what support gems work with what skills?
I find this to be a problem in general, some times it's mentioned in the support gem, but even then it can be unclear which gems are meant specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hover over a socketed Support Gem, it now shows what Skill Gems it affects by making them glow. The same is true for Skill Gems showing what Support Gems affect them. This currently does not properly handle the case of Support Gems that change a Skill Gem so that it enables or disables other Support Gems.

The support gems also have "tags" on them, which show what KIND of support gem they are. The support gems will work with all matching tags.

You can also view the current list of support gems [here](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Support_Skill_Gems)

Comment: It doesn't even need to be socketed. The Delve update added a tooltip when you hover over any support gem in inventory, vendors etc. that shows a list of your socketed active skills with an 'x' or a 'check'.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill Yeah true, there is a green check mark or a red X that shows compatibility when hovered.

Comment: A bonus to this is that on Path of Building you can add gems and hover over them, causing it to highlight all gems affected by the support